# Delphi - TEdit / TMaskEdit not displaying Asterisk (*) Passwordchar

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe3

I'm using **Delphi XE3** for VCL application development. 
I'm having **TMaskEdit** field in my form and i have set its ***PasswordChar*** property as Asterisk ( * ) . But when i execute the application it's displaying password character as Dot (.) instead of Asterisk ( * ).

[image]

Please help me on this.

Comment: This seems to happen when the project uses run-time Themes and the PassWordChar property is asterisk.

Comment: this is beyond your control as the common control runtime themes govern this. One option is to not use runtime themes but that is maybe not desired...

Comment: It's not . but ● :)

Comment: Turn off runtime themes in your project options, and the asterisk will appear. Of course, the rest of your app will look like it was written for Windows 2000, but you'll see the asterisk. Modern versions of Windows with themes enabled show  ● instead.

Comment: Or, you can disable themes for just the Edit control (using [`SetWindowTheme(Edit.Handle, 0, 0)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827.aspx)) instead of for the entire project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SendMessage(MaskEdit1.Handle, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, Ord('*'), 0);
```

You can put this on your FormCreate event or anywhere

Comment: This won't change anything if runtime themes are being used in the OS. At least, not since Windows 7.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what `PasswordChar` setter does?

Comment: I just have XE7 code at hand, there the setter will - if the Value changes - set `FPasswordChar := Value;` and then, when `HandleAllocated` call `RecreateWnd`. But in `TCustomEdit.CreateWnd` there then is a `SendMessage`call under following condition `if (FPasswordChar <> #0) and not (StyleServices.Enabled and ((FPasswordChar = '*'))) then`.

Comment: Yes, `TCustomEdit` already use `EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR` internally.  `'*'` is the default password char (that is documented behavior), `TCustomEdit.CreateWnd()` skips `EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR` when sending it would be redundant from the default behavior. The real issue is simply when visual themes are enabled, a password char of `'*'` is displayed by ComCtrl32 v6 as `●` and you can't change that behavior without disabling visual themes for the Edit control, if not the entire project.

Comment: @Fero68 , It worked for me. Thanks alot.
I have not truned off the runtime themes for my project , eventhough it worked for me. Thank you so much...!